# Saving the state of custom object - in onResume method

Tags: android, object, savestate

I have a object called custom obj in an activity , now when the user starts the app the object works perfectly fine, but suppose the user is in that activity and clicks on `HOME button` so now the activity goes to pause state , now after some may be 2 to 3 hrs the user resumes the activity but the object state is no longer avaiable, why is it so?

I have tried with onsaveInstanceState to store the object but not working?

Comment: Show us your code. `onSaveInstanceState()` is the proper way of doing it, but rather than restoring in `onResume()` you need to do it in `onCreate()`.

Comment: @323go ok how to restore it in oncreate?

Comment: See example in answer. Obviously, you'd need to extend that to save all your state variables.

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
int aNumber;
int aString;

@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle data ) {
    aNumber = data.getInt( "aNumber", 0 );
    aString = data.getString( "aString", "" );

    // .. set content and restore state
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle data ) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState( data );
    data.putInt( "aNumber", aNumber );
    data.putString( "aString", aString );
}
```

Comment: i have one more thing before going deep into this, can you help me?

Comment: Just post your question and I'll try to help. Leaving shortly though.

Comment: now i need to pass an object from one activity to other ? whats the best way to do it? and whats happening is as  said when the user resumes the activity after long time it gives me null,

Comment: There are two approaches to that: 1) You can implement the `Parcelable` interface for the object and pass it in the `Intent`. That is the preferred method. 2) Declare a singleton or a static singleton to hold the object reference. This is often considered hackish, but it has less overhead for very specific cases. http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3

Comment: Sure, just post it in the question.

Comment: hey can you please help me with one more issue?, with respect to parcelabel